# Change tmux prefix control keyboard shortcut to alt keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

Is it possible to change the `tmux` prefix keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes. See for example [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190820085631/http://mutelight.org/practical-tmux):

```
set-option -g prefix M-b
```

Comment: zsh: command not found: set-option

Comment: @alper `tmux` before, or add to ~/.tmux.conf, or <prefix>`:`

Answer (score 21):

Just extracted the link answered by @Lars Kotthof

Changing tmux prefix to Alt+b:

```
set-option -g prefix M-b
```

Answer (score 12):

As other have noted, you can do this by describing your favorite control sequence in e.g. the `~/.tmux.conf` config file.

```
set-option -g prefix M-b
```

You can also execute this from within tmux by using the `command-prompt` command, ie. the current prefix and the `:` character, to run the `set-option` command interactively.  I.e., type Ctrl-b then these characters, as is:

```
:set-option -g prefix M-b
```

followed by the Enter key